# featherlight.js tagetAttr and autostart function

Tags: featherlight.js

I was wondering about the purpose of the following attribute of the default configuration object. As per documentation on github:

> By default, Featherlight initializes all elements matching defaults.selector on document ready. If you want to prevent this, set $.featherlight.defaults.autostart to false before the DOM is ready.

And under "Bind featherlight section":

> It will then look for the targetAttr (by default "data-featherlight") on this element and use its value to find the content that will be opened as lightbox when you click on the element.

Give the above two, I am trying to:

1. Stop featherlight from loading and initializing itself on startup
2. Instead of using data-featherlight-xxx attributes, use data-my-lightbox-xxx attributes.

So I did the following:

In my javascript, before the onReady() function, I added:

```
$.featherlight.defaults.autostart=false;
```

and

```
$.featherlight.defaults.targetAttr='data-my-lightbox';
```

However, setting the autostart to false doesn't seem to have any effect. If I look at the source, I don't see any reference to it either. There is an 'autoBind' variable though.

Next, I tried setting the data-my-lightbox attribute on the anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" data-my-lightbox="my-image-gallery.html" ...>
```

and  also tried:

```
<a href="my-image-gallery.html" data-my-lightbox="iframe" ...>
```

but it seems like this is being ignored as well. Until I did the following:

```
$('[data-my-lightbox]').featherlight();
```

In a way that seems logical, but I was under the impression that if I change the default attribute before onReady, the rest would fall into place. Then I discovered the autoBind variable (before onReady()):

```
$.featherlight.autoBind='[data-my-lightbox]';
$.featherlight.defaults.targetAttr='data-my-lightbox';
```

that works without requiring the explicit $(..).featherlight construct. All good so far.

However, it seems that the width/height attributes for the iFrame should still be data-featherlight-xxxxx instead of data-my-lightbox-xxxx..perhaps attributed to the following line in source:

```
var match = this.name.match(/^data-featherlight-(.*)/);
```

What if I change that to something like:

```
var matchRegEx = RegExp("^"+targetAttr+"-(.*)"); 
var match = this.name.
```

and update the code in relevant places?

Thank you for your help and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [updated README](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/commit/27491ce9a6ef443e87f0687eceaa98929a988dde) reflects the fact that one should use `autoBind`, as you discovered.

With the latest release, you need to change the `namespace` option in addition to `autoBind` and `targetAttr` to get the results you seek.